# Using Iterators on a list of pointers

Tags: c++, list, iterator, operator-precedence

I am trying to iterator over a `list` of pointers:

```
int main () {
    list<Game*> Games;
    Games = build_list_from_file(); //Reading the games.info file
    list<Game*>::iterator it = Games.begin();
    it++;
    cout << *it->get_name() << endl ;
    //  ...
}
```

When I compile it, I have this error:

```
error: request for member ‘get_name’ in ‘* it.std::_List_iterator<_Tp>::operator-><Game*>()’, which is of pointer type ‘Game*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
  cout << *it->get_name() << endl ;
               ^
```

`Game` is a class that has the `get_name` member function, which returns the name of the game. What should I do to make this compile?

Comment: When working with iterators is a good idea use `auto`.

Comment: My question was a good one, because I think my mistake is common, thanks every one!

Comment: btw there is no `vector` in your code

Comment: @tobi303: It was working, so I don't copy it here

Comment: i see, but then I guess you used a different way to access the vectors element, maybe a loop with an `int` counter (?), because with a vector iterator you would run into the same problem.

Comment: @tobi303: your right, i used a different way, because vector elements are easy to reach, using a for loop is enough. I use vectors a lot, but problem indicates using lists.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have an issue with [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), try adding parentheses

```
(*it)->get_name()
```

Answer (score 7):

You've run into an [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) issue. `->` has higher precedence than `*`, so you're really doing:

```
*(it->get_name())
```

which doesn't compile since `Game*` doesn't have any members, much less `get_name`. You need to do the dereference first, which needs to be parenthesized:

```
(*it)->get_name()
```

Answer (score 6):

You should write `(*it)->get_name()` since `operator->` has higher precedence than dereference operator.

Answer (score 2):

It is all about operator precedence.

It should be `(*it)->get_name()`

If you can use C++11, then use auto for better readability.

```
int main (){
    list<Game*> Games;
    Games = build_list_from_file(); //Reading the games.info file
    auto it = Games.begin();
    it++;
    cout << (*it)->get_name() << endl ;
//  ...
}
```

Comment: auto is a great thing, Thanks.